# How to generate form and crud using Spring and React

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I want to dynamically generate crud form based on my API.

I am using spring, spring-data-rest and spring-hateoas.

I don't wan't to render react from java.

I was thinking of tweaking `/profile` and add some meta informations for rendering my form.

Does anyone has an implementation recommandations for me ?

I have seens that some react projects that is similar with what I require client side, but it is not adapted for spring:

https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Rest can return ALPS or JSON Schema, just change the Accept header:

```
Accept: application/schema+json
GET http://example.com/profile/foos
```

So, if you have an entity like:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Foo {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String owner;

    private String name;
}
```

You will get a response like:

```
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "properties": {
    "owner": {
      "title": "Owner",
      "readOnly": false,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "readOnly": false,
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {},
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form) project seems to fulfill the requirements. It uses JSON Schema to build Forms on the Client (in React).

Comment: Do you realize you just shared the link from my question, except the project was move to another organization :) ?

Comment: Nah I even didn't read the piece of information in your question that would've saved me some hours of experiments. That this thing is not made with Spring in mind. Well at least we have a updated link now. Did you find something better in the last years?